# print to printer doesn't work in .exe created by matlab

Tags: matlab, printing, executable

I wrote a function in MATLAB, which is creating random plots. After plotting 1000 random steps it sends the figure to the printer and prints the file. I used the deploy tool to make an .exe file. But the .exe file doesn't print the images. In MATLAB it works perfectly, but in the .exe it just ignores the print command. For the rest the .exe is working perfect.

The command I wrote to print is:

print -f1 '-PHP DeskJet 930C/932C/935C'

Does anyone know why this doesn't work in the .exe file and how i could make it work?

Thanks alot,
Elise

Comment: You may find some answers in Loren Shure's post - [printing in a deployed application](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/11/25/printing-in-a-deployed-application/)

Answer (score 0):

When printing from a deployed application, you need to use the command `deployprint` instead of `print`. If you need to use the application from within MATLAB as well as deployed, you can use the command `isdeployed`:

```
if isdeployed
    deployprint ...
else
    print ...
end
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. First it didn't work, with the -p function selecting the printer. but then i gave the command for using the printer drive, and now it works perfect in the deployed application. with the command:  `deployprint(f1,'-ddeskjet')`

Comment: Hey! I was wondering 1 thing: if run the function in MATLAB it works with the command `'-PHP DeskJet 930C/932C/935C'` but NOT with the comment `'-ddeskjet'`. but in the deployed application the command `'-ddeskjet'` works and the command `'-PHP DeskJet 930C/932C/935C'` does NOT work. Why is that? Just interested to learn the program.